# Create and XML File in Xcode cocoa Application?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I grab a XML file from server and Parse it with the NSXMLParser and display it in a NSTableView. From there, i can add a row to the tableview. I am guessing the added information is added to the arrayController(I am very new to Xcode and Objective-C, so i am not sure). Is there any way for me to get the information in that arrayController or TableView and pack it into an XML File, so i can upload that edited file to the server?

Thanks,
Elite Gamer

Comment: There are two aspects to your question. On is how to recognize the changes in the table and store it in local data. Once you know that that happens and in which format (an NSArray or whatever) you keep the data then ask the question on how to XML it. Does the XML format matter or are you rather free in formating it and just need "some proper xml"?

Comment: @HermannKlecker yes, i need a specific XML format. I have to re-parse the edited one, if i need to change it again. How can i write xml in Xcode?'